# merge rows based on index range pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Using tabula I have a dataframe of transactions from a pdf, which has the following layout:

```
|   | Details     | Transaction |
 --- ------------- -------------
| 0 | Date: 11:20 | Debit       |
| 1 | 01/01/2020  | $100.50     |
| 2 | Date: 13:15 | Credit      |
| 3 | 01/02/2020  | $50.00      | 
 --- ------------- -------------
```

I would like merge rows that are from the same transaction. In this case rows [0, 1] and [2, 3].

My idea was to find each row number with the string 'Date' and merge those rows.

```
index = list(df.index[df['Details'].str.contains('Date')]
>>> [0, 2]
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
|   | Details     | Transaction |
 --- ------------- -------------
| 0 | Date: 11:20 | Debit       |
|   | 01/01/2020  | $100.50     |
| 1 | Date: 13:15 | Credit      |
|   | 01/02/2020  | $50.00      | 
 --- ------------- -------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to create a grouper `g`, then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on `g` and `agg` using `join`:

```
g = df['Details'].str.contains('(?i)Date:').cumsum()
df = df.groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(' '.join)
```

Another idea (If the dataframe structure is fixed):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg(' '.join)
```

Result:

```
                  Details    Transaction
0  Date: 11:20 01/01/2020  Debit $100.50
1  Date: 13:15 01/02/2020  Credit $50.00
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but what if the 'Date:' value wasn't fixed and had a unique value (say a time) after the word 'Date:'. I have edited my example.